# Imagemagick on open wrt router "UnableToOpenConfigureFile"

Tags: openwrt, router, imagemagick

I have installed Open Wrt on my TP-Link TL-WR740N/ND v4. Everything works fine but the Imagemagick. I have installed it into ram (no enough space on rom ) with `opkg`

```
# opkg install imagemagick imagemagick-png imagemagick-jpeg imagemagick-tools -d ram
...
...
# opkg list-installed | grep imagema
imagemagick - 6.7.8-1
imagemagick-jpeg - 6.7.8-1
imagemagick-png - 6.7.8-1
imagemagick-tools - 6.7.8-1
```

but not I am getting `UnableToOpenConfigureFile` as there is no configuration files. Anyone knows how to omit that ?

```
# convert -debug configure picture.jpeg picture.jpeg 
2013-10-14T14:45:24+00:00 0:00.010 0.010u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2677]: utility.c/ExpandFilenames/939/Configure
  Command line: convert {-debug} {configure} {picture.jpeg} {picture.jpeg}
2013-10-14T14:45:24+00:00 0:00.020 0.020u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2677]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/share/ImageMagick-6.7.8/coder.xml"
2013-10-14T14:45:24+00:00 0:00.020 0.020u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2677]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/lib/ImageMagick-6.7.8/config/coder.xml"
2013-10-14T14:45:24+00:00 0:00.030 0.030u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2677]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/etc/ImageMagick/coder.xml"
2013-10-14T14:45:24+00:00 0:00.030 0.030u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2677]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.7.8/coder.xml"
2013-10-14T14:45:24+00:00 0:00.030 0.030u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2677]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/root/.magick/coder.xml"
2013-10-14T14:45:24+00:00 0:00.060 0.060u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2677]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/share/ImageMagick-6.7.8/magic.xml"
2013-10-14T14:45:24+00:00 0:00.070 0.070u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2677]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/lib/ImageMagick-6.7.8/config/magic.xml"
2013-10-14T14:45:24+00:00 0:00.070 0.070u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2677]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/etc/ImageMagick/magic.xml"
2013-10-14T14:45:24+00:00 0:00.070 0.070u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2677]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.7.8/magic.xml"
2013-10-14T14:45:24+00:00 0:00.070 0.070u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2677]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/root/.magick/magic.xml"
2013-10-14T14:45:24+00:00 0:00.090 0.090u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2677]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/share/ImageMagick-6.7.8/delegates.xml"
2013-10-14T14:45:24+00:00 0:00.090 0.090u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2677]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/lib/ImageMagick-6.7.8/config/delegates.xml"
2013-10-14T14:45:24+00:00 0:00.090 0.090u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2677]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/etc/ImageMagick/delegates.xml"
2013-10-14T14:45:24+00:00 0:00.090 0.090u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2677]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.7.8/delegates.xml"
2013-10-14T14:45:24+00:00 0:00.100 0.090u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2677]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/root/.magick/delegates.xml"
2013-10-14T14:45:24+00:00 0:00.100 0.090u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2677]: delegate.c/LoadDelegateList/1228/Configure
  Loading delegate configuration file "built-in" ...
convert: UnableToOpenConfigureFile `delegates.xml' @ warning/configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/591.
convert: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `picture.jpeg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
convert: NoImagesDefined `picture.jpeg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3044.
```

**EDIT**

I have now tried to copy my delegates from ubuntu box to router but no luck.

Now I just got rid of `UnableToOpenConfigureFile`

```
# convert -debug configure picture.jpeg picture.jpeg 
2013-10-14T15:14:34+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2789]: utility.c/ExpandFilenames/939/Configure
  Command line: convert {-debug} {configure} {picture.jpeg} {picture.jpeg}
2013-10-14T15:14:34+00:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2789]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/share/ImageMagick-6.7.8/coder.xml"
2013-10-14T15:14:34+00:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2789]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/lib/ImageMagick-6.7.8/config/coder.xml"
2013-10-14T15:14:34+00:00 0:00.020 0.000u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2789]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/etc/ImageMagick/coder.xml"
2013-10-14T15:14:34+00:00 0:00.020 0.000u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2789]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.7.8/coder.xml"
2013-10-14T15:14:34+00:00 0:00.020 0.000u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2789]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/root/.magick/coder.xml"
2013-10-14T15:14:34+00:00 0:00.020 0.000u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2789]: coder.c/LoadCoderList/693/Configure
  Loading coder configuration file "/usr/share/ImageMagick-6.7.8/coder.xml" ...
2013-10-14T15:14:34+00:00 0:00.050 0.030u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2789]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/share/ImageMagick-6.7.8/magic.xml"
2013-10-14T15:14:34+00:00 0:00.060 0.040u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2789]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/lib/ImageMagick-6.7.8/config/magic.xml"
2013-10-14T15:14:34+00:00 0:00.060 0.040u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2789]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/etc/ImageMagick/magic.xml"
2013-10-14T15:14:34+00:00 0:00.060 0.040u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2789]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.7.8/magic.xml"
2013-10-14T15:14:34+00:00 0:00.060 0.040u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2789]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/root/.magick/magic.xml"
2013-10-14T15:14:34+00:00 0:00.080 0.060u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2789]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/share/ImageMagick-6.7.8/delegates.xml"
2013-10-14T15:14:34+00:00 0:00.080 0.060u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2789]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/lib/ImageMagick-6.7.8/config/delegates.xml"
2013-10-14T15:14:34+00:00 0:00.080 0.060u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2789]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/etc/ImageMagick/delegates.xml"
2013-10-14T15:14:34+00:00 0:00.080 0.060u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2789]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.7.8/delegates.xml"
2013-10-14T15:14:34+00:00 0:00.090 0.060u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2789]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/564/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/root/.magick/delegates.xml"
2013-10-14T15:14:34+00:00 0:00.090 0.060u 6.7.8 Configure convert[2789]: delegate.c/LoadDelegateList/1228/Configure
  Loading delegate configuration file "/usr/share/ImageMagick-6.7.8/delegates.xml" ...
convert: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `picture.jpeg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
convert: NoImagesDefined `picture.jpeg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3044.
```

Comment: Try to copy all *.xml files from `/etc/ImageMagick`.

Comment: @jofel the problem is that I don't have any of those files 'installed' by `opkg` in my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the configure files (`delegates.xml` etc.) to a directory which imagemagick searches (`/root/.magick/` or `/usr/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.7.8/` or `/usr/share/ImageMagick-6.7.8/` or `/usr/lib/ImageMagick-6.7.8/config/` or `/etc/ImageMagick/`.)

If it should search in another directory, you can e.g. symlink on of these directories to the correct one, or need to recompile imagemagick.

Comment: Those files have not been installed with ImageMagick by `opkg`. May the package be broken then ?

Comment: @Patryk Yes, the package seems to be broken - it seems that the maintainers forgot to package the configuration file in a (possible separate) package. Feel free to report this bug to the responsible persons.